# Replace Firewalld with system-config-firewall-tui on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, security, webserver, firewalld

I have a question regarding firewall config on CentOS 7.

**What I have done**

1. Disabled firewalld with `systemctl stop firewalld.service`
2. Installed and configured `system-config-firewall-tui`
3. Tested my configuration, it works.

However, when I reboot it appears as thought Firewalld is back in charge and all I can do to get my ports open is to stop the firewalld service. As I don't know how to use Firewalld ***can anyone suggest how I can rip out and replace firewalld with system-config-firewall-tui?*** I am new to using CentOS but am fairly versed with Debian as a Server and Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

**UPDATE:** I would like to clarify that I don't want to rip out the firewall I simply want to replace `firewalld` with whatever `system-config-firewall-tui` uses, which I guess is `iptables`? Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

At step 1, try also doing this:

```
systemctl disable firewalld.service
```

`systemctl stop` stops the service immediately, but leaves it configured to start again whenever it would usually do so (i.e. on boot).

`systemctl disable` removes it from the boot process.

To stop it immediately and prevent it starting on next boot, run both.

`systemctl status firewalld.service` will tell you whether it's running or how it's configured